# trace-redisplay: How to see stderr from within Emacs?

Tags: debugging, redisplay

When building Emacs, I use `./configure --enable-checking='glyphs'` so that I can take advantage of some of the built-in tools such as `M-x trace-redisplay`.

The redisplay debugging messages can be seen if the GUI version of Emacs was launched from the terminal.

Instead of watching a separate terminal application while using Emacs, I would like to see the `stderr` output — in real time (if possible¹) — from within Emacs.  For example, I would like to do some stuff in one Emacs window and be able to see `stderr` output in another visible Emacs window.  How can I achieve that goal?

¹  <sub>Due to the nature of redisplay, the buffer that displays `stderr` (when this question is answered) may not be able to update until the next command loop?</sub>

Comment: I think it's better to ask this question on emacs-devel.  It's very specific to debugging Emacs' internals; it's unlikely that you'll get a proper answer here.

Comment: I don't know if this is a good idea. Here's why: if you make Emacs display debugging information about its redisplay code, then this debugging information will include messages about displaying this debugging information itself. (Hmm... I don't know if I'm making sense here.)

Comment: A low-tech solution is to redirect `stderr` to a file and simply visit that file, with `auto-revert-mode` enabled.

Comment: Maybe you could use `eshell` for starting a 2nd instance of `emacs`.

Answer (score 0):

One viable alternative is to create a message with a `Lisp_Object` instead, but beware that passing raw numbers without using functions like `make_number` or `make_float` will cause Emacs to crash.  This is not technically speaking the answer to the question, but it permits seeing values within Emacs and is not subject to the limitations of `GLYPH_DEBUG` (which cannot print a `Lisp_Object`).

```
Lisp_Object my_object_one = make_float (0.1);
AUTO_STRING (my_string_one, "This is the value of `my_object_one':  %s");
CALLN (Fmessage, my_string_one, my_object_one);

Lisp_Object my_object_two = make_number (777);
AUTO_STRING (my_string_two, "This is the value of `my_object_two':  %s");
CALLN (Fmessage, my_string_two, my_object_two);
```

The following examples use `fprintf` to generate output to STDERR (seen from a separate terminal that launched Emacs), converting `Lisp_Object` into usable information with `SSDATA`.  The usual formats apply. e.g., `%f` for float, `%d` for integer, `%s` for a string, etc.:

```
fprintf (stderr, "My lisp object:  %s\n", SSDATA (Fchar_to_string (make_number (101))));

fprintf (stderr, "string: %s | int: %d\n", SSDATA (build_string ("foo")), 69);
```